# In Rails, How To generate a 4 digit ID with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I need to generate a 4 digit unique ID using factory girl. I used `rand` but its not working. It will generate a random number and assign it to all records. How can I do this?

Here's how I used the rand method :

```
 nyaaid "NYAA/N/WP#{Random.rand(0002..9999)}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code could work if I understand your problem correctly.

`[1,1,1,1].map!{|x| (0..9).to_a.sample}.join`

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) to zero-pad your random number to four digits:

```
'%04d' % Random.rand(2..9999)
```

PS: `0002` doesn't mean what you probably think it does. The leading zero indicates that that number is in octal (look at `0010` in `irb` and you'll see `8`, not `10`). You're getting lucky because 2 is 2 in octal and decimal but you really should use `2..9999` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in {}

```
nyaaid { "NYAA/N/WP#{Random.rand(0002..9999)}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

FactoryGirl has sequences specifically for this case:

```
sequence(:nyaaid) { |n| sprintf("NYAA/N/WP%04d", n) }
```